# EF How to force inner join?

Tags: entity-framework

I have this ef method style

```
            List<Customer> customers = db.Customers.Where( s => s.IsActive == true )
                .Include( s => s.Communications.Select( a => a.Page ) )
                .Include( s => s.Communications.Select( a => a.Dealership ) )
                .Include( s => s.Communications.Select( a => a.Lead ) )
                .ToList();
```

it will output

```
SELECT 
    ...
    FROM ( SELECT 
        ... 
        CASE WHEN ([Join3].[CommunicationId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT ...
            FROM    [dbo].[Communication] AS [Extent2]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Page] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[PageId] = [Extent3].[PageId]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Dealership] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent2].[DealershipId] = [Extent4].[DealershipId]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Lead] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent2].[LeadId] = [Extent5].[LeadId] ) AS [Join3] ON [Extent1].[CustomerId] = [Join3].[CustomerId1]
        WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[IsActive]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[CustomerId] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

The problem is the LEFT OUTER JOIN, so it will return customer even Communication is empty. In entity class I also marked [Required] for both class Communication and Customer. How to force using inner join?

Comment: You can't make a collection "required".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal behavior of `.Include`, because, first of all, it requests main data, i.e. `Customers`, regardless of existance of dependent/related items. So, you should write query with `inner join`s manually:

```
var data = (from customer in db.Customers.Where(x => x.IsActive)
            join comm in db.Communications on customer.CustomerId equals comm.CustomerId1
            join page in db.Pages on comm.PageId equals page.PageId
            join dealer in db.Dealerships on comm.DealershipId equals dealer.DealershipId
            join lead in db.Leads on comm.LeadId equals lead.LeadId
            select new 
            {
                customer.CustomerId,
                comm.PageId,
                comm.DealershipId,
                comm.LeadId,

                //another required fields from any table
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the slower parts of executing a DBMS query is the transfer of the resulting data from your DBMS to your local process.

Your `Customer` has a zero or more `Communications`. Every `Communication` belongs to exactly one `Customer` using a foreign key: a simple one-to-many relationship. It could be that you designed a many-to-many relationship, the result will be similar.

Apparently you want to fetch some `Customers`, each with several properties of their `Communications`.

If you use include then the complete `Communications` object is fetched and transferred to your local process, inclusive all its properties, of which you only use Page / Dealership and Lead. You won't use `Communications.CustomerId`, because you know it will equal `Customer.Id`.

**General rule**

> Only use Include if you plan to change / update the fetched item. If you only want to read the values use Select. Select only the properties you really plan to use.

```
var result = myDbcontext.Customers
    .Where(customer => customer.IsActive)
    .Select(customer => new
    {
        // select only the customer properties you plan to use, for instance:
        Id = customer.Id,
        Name = customer.Name,

        Communications = customer.Communications
            .Select(communication => new
            {   // again: select only the properties you plan to use:
                Page = communication.Page,
                DealerShip = communication.DealerShip,
                Lead = communication.Lead,
            })
            .ToList(),
     });
```

If Page / Dealership / Lead are classes, again use a Select to fetch only the properties you need.

```
Page = communications.Page.Select(page => new
{
     Header = page.Header,
     Footer = page.Footer,
     Lines = page.Lines,
     ...
},
```

Normally a one-to-many relationship in Entity Framework is designed using `virtual ICollection<Communication>`. If you use this property, entity framework will know that an inner join is needed and perform it for you. This leads to fairly simple code

If for some reason you decided not to use the ICollection, you'll have to do the join yourself. The code will be similar:

```
var result = myDbcontext.Customers
    .Where(customer => customer.IsActive)       // Take only Active customers
    .GroupJoin(myDbContext.Communications,      // GroupJoin with Communications
    customer => customer.Id,                    // from every Customer take the Id
    communication => communication.CustomerId,  // from every Communication take the CustomerId
    (customer, communications) => new           // from every Customer with matching communications
    .Select(customer => new                     // make one new object
    {
        Id = customer.Id,
        Name = customer.Name,
        Communications = communications.Select(communication => new
        {
            Page = communication.Page,
            ...
        }
```